# telnet connection inputstream blocking why?

Tags: java, javascript, exec, inputstream, telnet

```
package burak;
import java.io.*;

public class telcon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String[] command=new String[2];
            command[0]="cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"telnet\"";
            command[1]="92.44.0.60";
            Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  
            try {
                p.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line=null;
            line=reader.readLine();
            File file =new File("rapor.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file);
            StringBuilder responseData=new StringBuilder();

            while(line!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                responseData.append(line);
                writer.write(line);
                writer.close();
            }

            BufferedReader stdInput=new BufferedReader(new           InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
            BufferedReader stdError=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String Error;

            while((Error=stdError.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(Error);  
            }

            while((Error=stdInput.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(Error);  
            }   
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i want to run telnet execute some commands i have two problem first when i connect to telnet it ask me username and password how ı contineude execute commands by using code after the enter password and my second question inputstream is not working readline is empty all time how can ı fix this problems.thanks for hel

Comment: you *can* use this:  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java  to do that.  However, you **cannot** do so programatically, which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the Apache Commons Net Java library (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) which contains various clients for many Internet protocols, including Telnet. I don't recommend you to use the embedded telnet client from the OS. Things will be cleaner with a library.

In addtion, in your first `while` loop, you're closing the `writer` object every iterations, and you don't read further with your `reader`.

Comment: i searched commons.apache but it is hard to understand for me  and i failed change code into what i want thats why i choose that code

Comment: Everything is explained in library's javadoc (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html). If you are planning to learn Java, you should start to learn to get used to libraries and API through Javadocs. Because you will frequently be facing both.

Comment: OutputStream outstr = tc.getOutputStream();
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int ret_read = 0;
do
{    try
    {
        ret_read = System.in.read(buff);
        if(ret_read > 0)      in this apache.common.telnet code the code read keybord in bytes can you give advice to read in string i need to send show ip ospf inter brief command

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java explains how to do that, but **not** programatically.